# PDF plotting unit in inches despite layout properties being set to mm

Tags: qgis, pdf

Noticed this when importing the PDF plots into AutoCAD at scale factor 1. The PDF plotter in QGIS is plotting an A4 sheet at 8.2639 x 11.7011 units (inches), despite the layout being set to mm and 210 x 297.

Is there a way to get the plotter to plot in mm units?

Comment: Is that just A4 in inches? If so you just need to change the settings on the cad